# My App Script is very slow how can I improve this?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

My script has many get and setvalues.I know it make script slower.
I want to improve my code but I'm not sure how can I do this.
I use this for seach information from another sheet.
It take 2-3 min sometime.

```
var wsformBN = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("formBN");
var wsCustomer = SpreadsheetApp.openById("SheetID").getSheetByName("SheetName");

//////////////

function clearCustomerInfo(){

wsformBN.getRange("C7:E8").clearContent();
wsformBN.getRange("C9:D12").clearContent();
wsformBN.getRange("H7:I11").clearContent();
wsformBN.getRange("H13:I15").clearContent();

}

//////////////

function searchCUtoBN(){
var values = wsCustomer.getDataRange().getDisplayValues();
var valuesFound=false;

for(var i=0 ; i<values.length; i++){
  var rowValue = values[i];
  var searchCustomerID = wsformBN.getRange("C4").getDisplayValue();

  clearCustomerInfo()

  if(rowValue[2] === searchCustomerID){    

    wsformBN.getRange("C7:E7").setValue(rowValue[3]);
    wsformBN.getRange("C8:E8").setValue(rowValue[4]);
    wsformBN.getRange("C9:E9").setValue(rowValue[5]);
    wsformBN.getRange("C10:E10").setValue(rowValue[6]);
    wsformBN.getRange("C11:E11").setValue(rowValue[7]);
    wsformBN.getRange("C12:E12").setValue(rowValue[8]);

    wsformBN.getRange("H7:I7").setValue(rowValue[11]);
    wsformBN.getRange("H8:I8").setValue(rowValue[12]);
    wsformBN.getRange("H9:I9").setValue(rowValue[13]);
    wsformBN.getRange("H10:I10").setValue(rowValue[14]);
    wsformBN.getRange("H11:I11").setValue(rowValue[15]);

    wsformBN.getRange("H13:I13").setValue(rowValue[17]);
    wsformBN.getRange("H14:I14").setValue(rowValue[18]);
    wsformBN.getRange("H15:I15").setValue(rowValue[19]);

    valuesFound=true;
    return;
  }}

   if (valuesFound==false){
clearCustomerInfo()
}};
```

If you know how to write the improve of this please help.
I really want this.

Comment: Welcome to [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).
See [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is not optimal, but if it really takes two to three minutes to run, chances are that the *spreadsheet* is on the heavy side. To improve spreadsheet performance, see [these optimization tips](https://support.google.com/docs/thread/102271339).

To improve the code, use `Range.setValues()`, like this:

```js
const wsformBN = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('formBN');
const wsCustomer = SpreadsheetApp.openById('SheetID').getSheetByName('SheetName');

function clearCustomerInfo() {
  wsformBN.getRangeList(['C7:E8', 'C9:D12', 'H7:I11', 'H13:I15',]).clearContent();
}

function searchCUtoBN() {
  clearCustomerInfo();
  const setValues_ = (rangeA1, values) => wsformBN.getRange(rangeA1)
    .offset(0, 0, values.length, values[0].length)
    .setValues(values);
  const searchCustomerID = wsformBN.getRange('C4').getDisplayValue();
  const values = wsCustomer.getDataRange().getDisplayValues();
  values.some(row => {
    if (row[2] === searchCustomerID) {
      const valuesC7e12 = row.slice(3, 8 + 1).map(value => [value, value, value]);
      setValues_('C7', valuesC7e12);
      const valuesH7i11 = row.slice(11, 15 + 1).map(value => [value, value]);
      setValues_('H7', valuesH7i11);
      const valuesH13i15 = row.slice(17, 19 + 1).map(value => [value, value]);
      setValues_('H13', valuesH13i15);
      return true;
    }
  });
}
```

See [Apps Script at Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/google-apps-script/info) and [Clean Code JavaScript](https://github.com/ryanmcdermott/clean-code-javascript).

Comment: Thank you so much. This really help a lot. Just need to edit a little for my sheet & try to learn from your code.